# Difference between tuple and int, and error unorderable types: tuple() < int()?

Tags: python, integer, tuples, openpyxl

I am getting an error which I am unable to understand properly. i.e. the difference between `tuple` and `int` as per the error. I read an answer but couldn't really understand it from a beginner(no coding background) standpoint.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "", line 7, in 
> File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py", line 300, in cell
> if row < 1 or column < 1:
> TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() < int()

Code:

```
import re, openpyxl, os, sys
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.compat import range
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

cont_us = ['hi','how','are']
wb = Workbook()
dest_filename = "Trying web.xlsx"
ws1 = wb.active
if cont_us:
    i=1
    for i in enumerate(cont_us,0):
        ws1.cell(row = i, column = 2).value = cont_us
        i = i+1
        wb.save(file_name = dest_filename)
```

Comment: A tuple is an immutable, hashable, ordered list of items (vs a regular Python list, which is mutable, and thus not hashable). An integer is... well, an integer (a whole number), and exactly *one* item.

Comment: This is python reporting a type error. It'll be a problem with the format of the data you're passing to openpyxl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) returns an iterable of tuples containing an index and the associated item. You should unpack accordingly to get an integer index (not tuple) that can be used to access a cell in the worksheet:

```
if cont_us:
    for i, x in enumerate(cont_us, 1):
        ws1.cell(row = i, column = 2).value = x # assign item, not list
wb.save(file_name = dest_filename)
```

More so, if you don't need the items in the list, you can simply use `range`:

```
if cont_us:
    for i in range(len(cont_us)):
        ...
```

On a side note, you don't need to initialise or increment `i`, the `for` loop already does that.

Comment: Thanks. I am still wrapping my brain around it. I do need the items in the list. Getting an error using the first code: _ValueError: Row or column values must be at least 1_

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. I am trying to remember how to start from row 2 now. I had it in an old code but it seems to do simply write the first value twice now B1 and B2 both have Hi. Trying to work it out.